# What to do to import a CSV file using a chromebook idle version python 3.7.3 shell

Tags: python-3.7, chromebook

Keep getting this error message when I enter this code :

```
data = pd.read_csv('1.01. Simple linear regression.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv('1.01. Simple linear regression.csv')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 678, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 440, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 787, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1014, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1708, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 384, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 695, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
```

And the message :

> FileNotFoundError: File b'1.01. Simple linear regression.csv' does not exist

Answer (score 0):

(Best end a question with the question.) The current working directory for the program does not have a file by that name.  Possible solutions:

1. Give a complete path to the file to `read_csv`.
2. Change the working directory in the program to the one that contain that file using `os.chdir`.  See [chdir doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#files-and-directories).
3. Start python in that directory, with or without IDLE, from a command line.

Comment: Thanks will try that now.